# can not kill a process in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I ran my command on the server ( linux, 3.17.8-gentoo-r1) but I lost my connection. I connected again and  I tried to kill and stop the process but I could not. I googled and tried different commands but none of them worked.

like:

```
kill 51376
kill -9 51376
kill -15 51376
...


PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
51376 john     20   0  0.190t 0.076t   3348 R  73.5 15.5 154:45.73 myScript
```

how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Login with same user in Linux by the user who runs the program.
2. Find the process by the command below:

   ```
   ps -ef | grep 51376
   ```

   (where 51376 is the PID)
3. If you are getting an output that shows the PID is still running, then simply run the command below:

   ```
   kill -9 51376
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but when I make a top, it is still running

Comment: john    51376     1 99 Mar28 ?        03:08:16 /home/john/myScript -c ctlr -d infile.test -o out.test
john    52971 52750  0 01:46 pts/19   00:00:00 grep --colour=auto 51376

Comment: Are you sure you logged in with user john, To make sure execute command `whoami`

Comment: yes. it is correct. I only have one account to access the server

Comment: Looks like this process has become a zombie process or its hanging. its better to find the parent of it if its exist however it can be or not. Just execute `pstree 51376` if there is any output then kill the parent and you will be done.All the best.

Comment: yes, it returned the name of the command . thank you very much. would you please tell me how can I kill the parent?

Comment: After executing this command `pstree 51376` you will get parent's PID only if it exist otherwise not.

Comment: pstree 51376
 returns myScript

Answer (score 0):

Dude, have you tried to kill the parent process (ppid)?

You can see the ppid via:

> top

then press "g+2"

Comment: its ppid is 1, is it possible to kill it?